# Prove whether $f(n)$ is $O$, $o$, $\Omega$, $\omega$ or $\Theta$ of $g(n)$. $f(n) = n + (\log n)^{2}$, $g(n) = n + \log(n^{2})$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

$f(n) = n + (\log n)^{2} , g(n) = n + \log(n^{2} ).$

Now so far I've done $g(n) = n+ 2\log(n)$

and then I think since its the same change to both, I can remove $n$.

leaving me with $f(n) = (\log n)^{2}$ and $g(n) = 2\log(n)$ now if I do $f(n)/g(n)$ I  get

$((\log n)^{2}) / (2\log n)$

and since the numerator is growing exponentially and the bottom is growing linearly? As we approach positive infinity the function approaches positive infinity. Thus $f(n)$ is $\omega$ of $g(n)$?

I don't know if this proof is done right, if its what is a better alternative? I am still new to this and learning!

Comment: Don't remove $n$. Do $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+(\log(n))^2}{n+2\log(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+(\log(n))^2/n}{1+2(\log(n))/n}=1$.

Comment: what should I do instead then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {f(n)} {g(n)}=\frac {n+(\log\, n)^{2}}{ n+2\log\, n}=\frac {1+(\log\, n)^{2}/n} { 1+2(\log\, n)/n} \to 1$

Comment: Did you just divide by n on the top and bottom?

Comment: @Brownie Yes, that is what I did. To see that the second terms in the numerator and denominator both tend to $0$ you can apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Sorry I know this is a bit later, I still dont understand how the f(n)/g(n) tends to 1. The numerator and denominator tend towards 0 as it is, and even after applying l'hopital's rule. I am confused

Comment: @Brownie Use L'Hopital's Rule to show that $\frac {\log\, n} n \to 0$ and $\frac {(\log\, n)^{2}} n \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much done with $O$ by doing the $g(n) = n+ 2\log(n)$ transformation, since 
$$f(n) = n + (\log n)^{2}  \\
g(n) = n + 2 \log(n)$$
Assuming that $\log$ means $\ln$:
$$\forall n \ge 8 \quad f(n) > g(n)$$
Since $\ln(8) > 2$, and $ln$ is monotone increasing.

This means that $g(n) = O(f(n))$.

Comment: log is base 2 in this case

Comment: Which is less information than $f\sim g$.